# Little problem with pointer to object in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

Consider the following code:

```cpp
class test {
    public:
    int n;
    test(int n) : n(n) {}
};

int main() {
    vector<test> v;
    test one(1), two(2);
    v.push_back(one);
    v.push_back(two);
    // obviously doesn't work since a copy of the object is stored in 
    //the vector ==> different memory addess
    test* p1 = &one;

   // also doesn't work properly since when the object gets erased,
   //this pointer is pointing to a different object
    test* p2 = &v[0]; 

    v.erase(v.begin());
    // prints 2 since object two was copied to the place of object one
    cout << p2->n << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

I want a pointer that points to a specific object in a vector and, when earring this object the pointer should also get deleted or point to null or something like that. Also when I have a pointer to an object at position 3 of a vector, I want this pointer to point, after removing e.g. object 1, to position 2 since object 3 "moved" one position to the left. Is something like this realisable or should I try a different approach? I just started learning C++ so I'm not very familiar to any advance concepts.

Comment: Would a vector of `shared_ptr`s work for you? You could then create `weak_ptr`s to their elements.

Comment: It sounds like you want [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) objects in the `std::vector`, and [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) to reference to those objects.

Comment: Also note that your example code has more issues. Even if you don't delete an element in the vector, a pointer to it can still become invalid when the vector's capacity changes and all of its elements are moved to a new location.

Comment: @AVH yes, I also know about this issue, but good to hear that smart pointers can help me in this case

Comment: If you are not stuck with a big project where you are bound to solve the problem in given manner ,,, I'll suggest to post original problem and above as proposed solution . So people can propose better alternates if possible. This one feel like you are inviting a world of pain for future change in requirements

Comment: @saumitramallick I started learning c++ 2 days ago, so I'm currently in a phase where I test everything out. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was said, you should use std::shared_ptr with std::weak_ptr. Below is a rewrite of your code with modern approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class test {
    public:
    int n;
    test(int n) : n(n) {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<test>> v;
    std::shared_ptr one = std::make_shared<test>(1);
    std::shared_ptr two = std::make_shared<test>(2);
    v.push_back(one);
    v.push_back(two);

    std::weak_ptr<test> p1 = one;
    std::weak_ptr<test> p2 = v[0]; 
    
    // prints 1 two times
    if (auto sp = p1.lock()) {
        std::cout << sp->n << std::endl; 
    }
    if (auto sp = p2.lock()) {
        std::cout << sp->n << std::endl; 
    }
    
    // delete all references to one
    v.erase(v.begin());
    one = nullptr;
 
    // nothing gets printed
    if (auto sp = p1.lock()) {
        std::cout << sp->n << std::endl; 
    }
    if (auto sp = p2.lock()) {
        std::cout << sp->n << std::endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00b2072bb8cd73ad